# Error during the installation of utf8 package

Tags: r

I am trying to install ‘utf8’ package (version 1.1.3) on my laptop but I got an error. I am using R 3.4.3 and my OS is macOS Sierra 10.12.6.

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘utf8’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/utf8/libs/utf8.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/utf8/libs/utf8.so, 6): Symbol not found: _utf8lite_graph_measure
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/utf8/libs/utf8.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/utf8/libs/utf8.so
Errore: loading failed
Esecuzione interrotta
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/utf8’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/utf8’
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my `~/.R/Makevars` file was corrupted. I had this line in the file:

```
PKG_LIBS = -fopenmp -lgomp
```

instead of

```
LDLIBS = -fopenmp -lgomp
```